# Wodpress Query Parameter (?p) Redirect if not numeric

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, redirect, wordpress-theming

The following is used in wordpress to get result of specific post

```
site_url?p=12
```

But what if it is not numeric. Lets try with `site_url?p=test` Instead of going to 404 It shows blank page? Tried to redirect with regex

```
^site_url?p=[0-9]
```

But It didn't worked out. Since this **p** is reserved keyword in wordpress.

Any Idea how can I check its value so that I can make condition if it is not numeric?

Comment: Are you aware that `?` is a meta character in regex, and needs to be escaped? `\?`?

Comment: I am using [redirect plugin](https://redirection.me/support/redirect-regular-expressions/) and it does allow me to add `?` without \?

Comment: Are you sure? `If you want to match a character that is part of the regular expression syntax then you must escape it. For example, if you want to match ? then you will need to put \? as ? on its own has a special meaning.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hook into `template_redirect` action hook to redirect the user to a specific page, NO PLUGIN NEEDED!

For example, the following code will redirect the user to your website `home_url` if `?p` is not numeric.

```php
add_action('template_redirect', 'your_theme_custom_page_redirect');

function your_theme_custom_page_redirect()
{
    global $wp_query;

    if (isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] != preg_match("~[0-9]~", $_GET['p']) && !is_admin()) {
        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header(404);
        wp_safe_redirect(home_url());
        exit;
    };
};
```

If you'd like to redirect the user to a `404` page and you have already created one, then, depending on your `404` page path and where it's located, you could do something like this:

```php
add_action('template_redirect', 'your_theme_custom_page_redirect');

function your_theme_custom_page_redirect()
{
    global $wp_query;

    if (isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] != preg_match("~[0-9]~", $_GET['p']) && !is_admin()) {
        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header(404);
        get_template_part(404); // This could change depending on the actual path of your 404 page
        exit;
    };
};
```

The code goes to `functions.php` file of your active theme.

Comment: However I used `/^[0-9]*$/` to validate for  numerica only

Comment: Yea that'd work too. It all depends on how you want to set it up.